# Не устанавливаеться библиотека silero

Tags: python, pytorch

пишу в консоль:

```
pip install silero==0.4.1
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Collecting silero==0.4.1
  Using cached silero-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.10.0 (from silero) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.10.0
```

Пытался torch отдельно установить, такая же фигня

Comment: Можно узнать версию OS, и пайтон.

Comment: Вот что нарыл  "настоящее время PyTorch для Windows поддерживает только Python 3.7–3.9" и обязательно Python x64

Comment: @Александр, понял у меня 3.11

Comment: можете установить 3.9 рядом только не запутайтесь

Comment: @Александр, спасибо, попробую так сделать